# libuv - free write buffer

Tags: c++, node.js, libuv

The documentation for `uv_write` states [[1](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html#c.uv_write)]:

> **Note** The memory pointed to by the buffers must remain valid until the callback gets called. This also holds for uv_write2().

So a dynamic allocation might be needed for the buffer's base. The calling function can look like the following:

```
void write_to_stream(uv_stream_t* stream) {   
    uv_write_t* write_req = new uv_write_t;
    uv_buf_t buf{};
    buf.base = new char[1024];
    buf.len = 1024;
    // fill the buffer
    uv_write(write_req, stream, buf, 1, on_write);
}
```

In this case the memory allocated by `new char[1024]` needs to be valid until the `on_write` callback is fired.

Looking at the signature of the callback `void on_write(uv_write_t* req, int status)` it is not obvious how to free this memory since there seems to be no way to access this pointer from within the callback.

```
void on_write(uv_write_t* req, int status) {
    // how to find the memory allocated for req's buffer?
    delete[] ???;
}
```

What's the intended way to free this memory once it's no longer needed?

Answer (score 2):

Since `libuv` is a c library, its structures should be standard-layout type. Therefore, you can wrap your `uv_write_t` and `uv_buf_t` in a context structure, and later cast back to the context structure. See the following example:

```cpp
struct write_context_t {
    uv_write_t write_req;
    uv_buf_t buf;
    ~write_context_t() {
        delete[] buf.base;
    }
}

void on_write(uv_write_t* req, int status) {
    write_context_t* context = reinterpret_cast<write_context_t*>(req);
    /* Do stuff ... */
    delete context;
}

void write_to_stream(uv_stream_t* stream) {   
    write_context_t* write_req = new write_context_t;

    /* fill your write_req and buf info here ... */

    // initiate write
    uv_write(&write_req.write_req, stream, write_req.buf, 1, on_write);
}
```

This works because pointer to the first non-static data member of a standard layout object is inter-convertible with a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is by using the `data`.  Note all uv-handles contains a `data` field which one can use for his own needs.

```
void write_to_stream(uv_stream_t* stream) {   
    uv_write_t* write_req = new uv_write_t;
    write_req.data = new char[1024];

    uv_buf_t buf{};
    buf.base = write_req.data;
    buf.len = 1024;

    // fill the buffer
    uv_write(write_req, stream, buf, 1, on_write);
}

void on_write(uv_write_t* req, int status) {

    delete[] req.data;
    delete req;
}
```

Comment: Note that deleting through a `void` pointer is undefined behavior in c++.